# Замена символов в строке php

Tags: php

Есть строка `300 руб.` Нужно оставить только цифры, не могу понять как это сделать.
preg_replace не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
echo (int) '300 руб';
```

Приведение к `int` возьмет числовую часть и отбросит всё остальное.

Еще вот так можно:

```
echo 0 + '300 руб'; // echo '300 руб' + 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. int отличный способ, надо запомнить :)